# eBay API: how to get the weight and dimensions when listing items

Tags: request, ebay-api

I'm trying to get the dimensions of some items using the finding service from ebay.

I tried adding the `outputSelector=UnitPriceInfo`, but there is no change.

My current request looks something like this:

> http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?OPERATION-NAME=findItemsAdvanced&SERVICE-VERSION=1.0.0&SECURITY-APPNAME=MYAPPID&GLOBAL-ID=EBAY-US&keywords=XBOX&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=50&itemFilter(0).name=ListingType&itemFilter(0).value(0)=FixedPrice&itemFilter(1).name=Condition&itemFilter(1).value=New&outputSelector(0)=UnitPriceInfo

Thank you.

Comment: Did you get a solution?

Comment: Nop, the project has been droped since 2016, I got a direct response from eBay and they told me back then, that there was no way to get that info. Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is 100% related, but I had problems getting the weight and dimensions using GetItemCall - They kept coming out as zeroes.

It turns out that I'd looped through Transactions on OrderType and passed in all the keys that I could find, inclusing the Item.TransactionId.

Turns out that if you only pass ItemID, and don't pass TransactionId, the weight and dimensions come through properly.

Might be the same with FindingService, might not.

Mark